# SVG text will not appear via D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I looked high and low.  But every guide failed me.  Why does text refuse to appear on my SVG canvas?

I am using D3.  Here is the relevant javascript code.  Let me know what other information you need.

```
var width = $('body').width(),
    height = $(window).height()

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]) // minus a 10 pixel buffer?  we should really get the width of #chart !!!

x.domain([0, d3.max(_.pluck(graph.nodes, 'x'))])


links = svg.selectAll('.link').data(graph.links) // links before nodes so that lines in SVG appear *under* nodes
    .enter().append('line')
        .classed('link', true)
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow-head)') // add in the marker-end defined above

var texts = svg.selectAll('text').data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
        .text( function (d) { return "some string"; })
        .attr({
            x: d => d.x,
            y: d => d.y,
            'font-family': "sans-serif",
            'font-size': "20px",
            'text-anchor': "middle",
            fill: "red",
        })

nodes = svg.selectAll('.node').data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
        .classed('node', true)
        .attr({
            r: 12,
            opacity: 0,
        })
        .call(drag)
```

The links work great.  The nodes work great (although I set their opacity to 0 just in case the text was hiding behind them.  The text has never worked.

There are no errors in the javascript console, but one warning: "Calling CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() with one argument is deprecated. Please pass the index argument as well: insertRule(x, 0).".  I don't think it's related.

Here is the HTML of the SVG after it has been dynamically generated for 4 nodes:

```
<svg width="1440" height="802">
    <defs fill="green">
        <marker class="arrow-head" id="arrow-head" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="21" refY="0" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
            <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path>
        </marker>
    </defs>

    <line class="link" marker-end="url(#arrow-head)" x1="754.0426851654547" y1="374.5980897296999" x2="752.8325728896963" y2="420.70270229471504"></line>
    <line class="link" marker-end="url(#arrow-head)" x1="677.2395972547282" y1="405.1687095552065" x2="710.2028024386651" y2="437.39885286852365"></line>
    <line class="link" marker-end="url(#arrow-head)" x1="710.2028024386651" y1="437.39885286852365" x2="752.8325728896963" y2="420.70270229471504"></line>

    <text x="40" y="40" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">some string</text>
    <text x="80" y="80" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">some string</text>
    <text x="160" y="160" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">some string</text>
    <text x="0" y="20" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">some string</text>

    <circle class="node" r="12" opacity="0" cx="754.0426851654547" cy="374.5980897296999"></circle>
    <circle class="node" r="12" opacity="0" cx="752.8325728896963" cy="420.70270229471504"></circle>
    <circle class="node" r="12" opacity="0" cx="677.2395972547282" cy="405.1687095552065"></circle>
    <circle class="node" r="12" opacity="0" cx="710.2028024386651" cy="437.39885286852365"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have `text` elements on the canvas already?

Comment: Put the style stuff inside a style attribute for one thing.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No, I do not.  I'll try to create one manually somehow...

Comment: Also, post the HTML as it is after you execute the code. That would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you @CoolBlue, this has certainly uncovered something!  The height and width of the svg container is not being factored into the x and y coordinates of the text.  For some reason this seems to happen automatically for the other things.  I will add some more relevant code...

Comment: Normally you would do this `.style({'font-family': "sans-serif",'font-size': "20px",'text-anchor': "middle",fill: "red"})`

Comment: Okay, I added the current code related to scaling coordinates.  So I guess it's just a matter of understanding that and seeing why it's not being applied to the text elements (and is being applied to the others).

Comment: Yes, you haven't posted the code where you use the scale to do the positioning so we can't really help with that, but I'm sure you can figure it out anyway. Meanwhile, its a lot simpler to use a `g` element as the node (with the datum bound to it) and append the `circle` and `text` on that. Then you can position the node `g` using a transform translate attribute. There are plenty of examples arround for how to do this in force directed graphs. Again, I'm sure you can figure that out for yourself.

Comment: I've added that relevant code (see top of JS portion).  But anyway, I can see the text now thanks to moving the info you said to `style()`, and leaving the `x` and `y` stuff in the `.attr()` section.  I read somewhere that it was okay to put style things in the attribute section.  I guess not!!!!

Comment: @CoolBlue So if you want the credit for finding the `style` issue, which was causing the texts to not appear (and is the correct answer to this SO question), please post the answer briefly below.  Thanks!!

Comment: Well, I posted that answer but decided to delete it as I don't think it was the problem.  I hadn't seen that method before and it's certainly not idiomatic, but when I tested it it worked in all major browsers.  I think the main point for you is to look at the output HTML and that's not really an answer I think.

Comment: Well your SVG works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p19ro1gq/ It's probably some CSS you're including that renders the text invisible. The difference between `.attr()` and `.style()` for style attributes is that `.style()` will override things set in CSS whereas `.attr()` doesn't.

Comment: There you go, @LarsKotthoff has the correct answer I think.

Comment: Indeed, my CSS was coloring the text white.  Of all things...